# Yelp API search request with iteration - How to make the iteration

Tags: java, loops

Below I have my code for a search request. As yelp only allows to get only 50 results I have a problem to make it work.

So basically offset = 0 and limit = 50 will bring me the results 0-50
             offset = 50 and limit = 50 will bring me the results 51-100

So and in my case I need 1000 Results. How can I manage it? I tried everything in my power and now I need some help.

```
    public class Search2 {
    static HttpURLConnection conn;
        public static void Searche() {

            int offset = 0;
            int limit = 50;

            try {

    for (int i = 0; i < 950; i=+50) {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=" + gui.Lead_1.tFOrt.getText()
        + "&categories=" + gui.Lead_1.tFKeyword.getText() + "&offset=" + i + "&limit=50");

     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        }

                try {
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + dbb.Pfad.getPath() + " ");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                // throwing the error message if the response is not available.
                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());

                }

                // capturing the response and appending it to the response string.
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
                String output;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(output);
                }

                // converting the response to the JSONObject.
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
                JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("businesses");
                JSONObject details = new JSONObject();
                // capturing the specific values(name, rating, reviewcount) from the response
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {


                    String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    int rating = arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("rating");
                    int review_count = arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("review_count");

                    JSONObject address = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location");

                    details.put("Name", name);

                    details.put("Rating", rating);
                    details.put("Review Count", review_count);

                    details.put("Address", address);
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("restaurant " + (i + 1), details);
                    list1.put(object);


                    Lead_2.row[0]=i+1;

                    Lead_2.row[1]=arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

                Lead_2.row[2]=arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("address1");
                    Lead_2.model.addRow(Lead_2.row);
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal, reproducible and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).